# Overlapping blessings

Tags: halacha, blessing, meal-seudah

Towards the end of a bread-based meal someone decides to have, in addition to their original plans, a hot drink (eg tea).

After the meal, they say *birkas hamazon*. Only after this do they then realise that they have drunk only half of the drink - half of it still remains. Would they be permitted to say *borei nefashos* after finishing the drink?

Answer (score 1):

Once birkat hamazon has been said, the blessing on the drink is no longer valid, so a fresh blessing has to be made on the remaining portion of the drink; that in turn requires borei nefashos.

*(information provided in now deleted comments under question)*

Comment: Sources for your claims would improve your answer immensely.

Comment: @msh210 the poster who gave me the information that I worked into this answer - they're not *my* claims - didn't give any sources. Since his comments have now been deleted I can't see his name to be able to ping him and ask for help. Perhaps someone else knowledgeable might be moved to provide the correct sources?

Comment: Perhaps it was @Danny Schoemann ?

Comment: or was the poster @hazoriz ?